# Expressing a number as the sum of two triangular numbers

Tags: c++, triangular

A triangular number or triangle number counts objects arranged in an equilateral triangle.

Their formula is:

```
n(n+1)/2
```

I want to write a number as the sum of two triangular numbers:

```
( 24=21+3 ; 48=45+3 )
```

I have written some code in C++ that does this pretty well for smaller numbers. But as N gets bigger, it becomes slower and slower, which makes me think my code is inefficient or downright wrong.

It generates the number `i` and gives `j` the value of `x-i`. It tests if both the numbers are triangular (iok, jok), and if they are, it prints them out and ends. If it doesn't find such numbers, it prints "NO".

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long x;
    cin>>x;
    long long j,i;
    int iok,jok;
    long sum;
    long long n;

    for(i=1;i<=x;i++){
        iok=0;
        sum=0;
        for (n=1; sum<=i; n++)
        {
            sum = sum + n;
            if (sum==i)
                iok=1;
        }
        j=x-i;
        jok=0;
        sum=0;
        for (n=1; sum<=j; n++)
        {
            sum = sum + n;
            if (sum==j)
                jok=1;
        }
        if(jok && iok){
            cout<<i<<" "<<j;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout<<"NO";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Thomas Sablik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4645334/thomas-sablik) said:

> Your algorithm has a time complexity of O(n^2) but you can solve the problem with one loop with complexity of O(n). Iterate over n, create the nth triangular number, subtract it from input and check if the result is a triangular number.